# How to compare performance of probability estimating model

Tags: probability, estimation, model, model-evaluation

Suppose I have a model that estimates a discrete probability distribution over a set of classes/factors `c1, c2, c3`.

What are the options and appropriate use cases of measuring performance given a test set of feature vectors and their labels?

**Few options that come to mind**

1. Maximum likelihood: measure probability of observing the class labels in the test set under the given model;
2. Assume that, for example, a test vector with a class label of `c1` represents a collapsed probability distribution $(1, 0, 0)$. Then use a similarity measure (or a loss function) to compare these probability distributions with the predicted probability;
3. Use a derived measure of expected utility $\mathbb{E}(U)$ based on application. Suppose further that we are modeling a game where the classes are possible outcomes of playing and there is an utility $U(c_i)$ associated with each class. Assume we would play whenever $\mathbb{E}(U) > 0$ in the model and our pay-off would be the utility of the actual class label or $0$ if we chose not to play. Then use pay-off over test set as a performance measure.

Comment: Is this question perhaps the same as the one at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/how-can-i-determine-accuracy-of-past-probability-calculations?

Comment: Yeah it is, thanks, scoring functions is exactly it.