# How to validate predicted proportions from a model when the proportions are not constant?

Tags: forecasting, predictive-models, prediction-interval, model-evaluation

I've built a model that tries to evaluate the percentage chance of winning for all NHL games.  For example:

1. Ana vs Bos (Bos- 57% chance of winning)
2. Chi vs Mtl (Mtl - 51% chance of winning)
3. LA vs Det (Det- 80% chance of winning)

The model is updated daily to take into account what happened in the latest games. At the end of the season, how can I validate my model against the actual results?

If my percentages were a fixed set (55%, 75%, 95%), it would be easy to validate. My model should be right 55% of time for all games that have a 55% chance of winning. My model should be right 95% of time for all games that have a 95% chance of winning.

But since my percentages are all different I don't know how to deal with them.  For example, I have predicted percentages like: 51.5%, 53,2%, 54.9%, 62.4%, 88.1%, etc. These came from my model. I'm using a lot of historical data to predict the winner (past games, goalie stats, active players, home vs away, etc., it is similar to the odd column on [this page](https://www.teamrankings.com/mlb-win-picks/)).

Comment: What do you mean that they are "all different"?

Comment: @Tim ex: 51.5%, 53,2%, 54.9%, 62.4%, 88.1%, etc..

Comment: But *why* that happens? What are those numbers?

Comment: These are coming from my model. I'm using a lot of historical data to predict the winner (past games, goalie stats, active players, home vs away, etc). Similar to the odd column on this page => https://www.teamrankings.com/mlb-win-picks/

Comment: It would be better if you could edit the information from your final comment directly into the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

The situation here is often covered under the heading of scoring rules. See for example [this question and answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/how-can-i-determine-accuracy-of-past-probability-calculations?noredirect=1&lq=1). One popular way of doing this is the [Brier score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brier_score). The Brier score is basically the average squared discrepancy between what you predicted (which is a proportion) and what did happen (which is 0 or 1).

Comment: Thank you, ,my predictions are very similar to weather predictions :) 
Rain = Win,
No rain = Loss

Answer (score 1):

You can use cross entropy.  See the wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy) especially the part on logistic regression.  The idea is if Boston wins you evaluate $\ln(x)$ and when Boston losses you evaluate $\ln(1-x)$ where $x$ is the probability your model outputs.  You can combine this into one formula: $y\ln(y) + (1-y)\ln(1-x)$. $y$ is the actual result (win or loss).  You can use this to evaluate your model and use this as your loss function.

Comment: what if you have more than 2 outcomes?

Comment: http://wiki.fast.ai/index.php/Log_Loss