# Name of mean absolute error analogue to Brier score?

Tags: classification, error, validation, scoring-rules

Yesterday's question [Determine accuracy of model which estimates probability of event](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/20534/4598) got me curious about probability scoring.

The [Brier score](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brier_score)
$$\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits _{i=1}^{N}(\text{prediction}_i - \text{reference}_i)^2$$
is a mean squared error measure.
Does the analogous mean absolute error performance measure
$$\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits _{i=1}^{N}|\text{prediction}_i - \text{reference}_i|$$
have a name, too?

Comment: Google allowed me to find [this paper](http://diskworld.wharton.upenn.edu/research/calibration_via_blackwell.pdf) where something very similar is named $L_1$-calibration score. Note that this score is a bit different than yours, anyway "$L_1$ score" seems the good keyword.

Comment: What search terms did you use? Googling I mainly learned how many different tumour scores exist (L1 meaning lymphnode involvement in that context)...

Comment: Something like "L1 score probability"... may be I've been lucky

Comment: Or google tries to help me and thinks I'm looking for tumours because that's what I do more often... "probability near score L1" got me to the paper below.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Answer seems to be: no, because MAE doesn't lead to a proper scoring rule.

See [Loss Functions for Binary Class Probability Estimation and Classification: Structure and Applications](http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~buja/PAPERS/paper-proper-scoring.pdf) where the MAE is discussed under "Counterexamples of proper scoring rules".

Comment: @amoeba: There you are