# Recalibrating a model predictions to incidence in coarse resolution, and measuring that its calibrated

Tags: regression, predictive-models, goodness-of-fit, calibration, isotonic

I have a model that predicts a rare disease (1% prevalence) with good discrimination (AUC). However, the predictions it is giving can not be interpreted as probabilities.

I want to recalibrate the predictions according to the prevalence in the population - and I do not need high resolution, I need 5 bins (levels) of probability - from "very low" to "high" (so I probably don't need sophisticated `isotonic regression` or `platt scaling`), but I do need a calibrated **probability for every bin**.

I tried 'learning' the probabilities for these bins from a 'train' set representing the population and then testing that the model is calibrated on a 'validation' set with the `Hosmer-Lemeshow` statistic.

However, the statistic is very unstable and the p-value varies from 0.0012 to 0.28 when I repeat this experiment with different random sets. **Why is this happening?** The entire population size is 4763615 out of which there are 48606 cases. I'm dividing it 70%/30% between train/validation sets. I tried dividing the bins in many ways (equal samples in each bin, equal cases in each bin, equal delta of original predictions..). **Is my entire approach reasonable? or is there something else I'm missing?**

(related to [Evaluating logistic regression and interpretation of Hosmer-Lemeshow Goodness of Fit](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/169438/evaluating-logistic-regression-and-interpretation-of-hosmer-lemeshow-goodness-of), but not specific to logistic-regression. Also related to [How to choose optimal bin width while calibrating probability models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/180058/how-to-choose-optimal-bin-width-while-calibrating-probability-model-using-brier)).

Comment: I think the questions which you yourself relate to, are actually also applicable here. Especially @FrankHarrell's answer to the first question referenced to (concerning the nature of the H-L test) is applicable. Also, AFAIK, in order to calculate similar measures of a model's calibration, it does not matter how the predicted probabilities <of a dichotomous outcome> are obtained, as long as these probabilities are actually estimated by the model (so models which only classify patients into outcome yes/no are out).

Comment: Hosmer-Lemeshow is considered obsolete:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/273966/logistic-regression-with-poor-goodness-of-fit-hosmer-lemeshow