# Bandwidth selection for smooth reliability diagram

Tags: estimation, reliability, kernel-smoothing

Following up on ["How to evaluate quality of probability estimator for Bernoulli experiments?"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28338/how-to-evaluate-quality-of-probability-estimator-for-bernoulli-experiments), I want to visualize the quality of an estimator for probability forecasting using a [Reliability Diagram](http://www.ecmwf.int/products/forecasts/guide/The_reliability_diagram.html).
I do not however want to put the observations into "bins", which seems to me an unprecise estimation, but rather estimate the reliability using a smoothing process similar to [Kernel Smoothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_smoother).

So, given $n$ observations $o_i \in \{0,1\}$ and $n$ predictions $\hat{p}_i \in [0,1]$, I want to estimate $f(x)=\frac{\sum_{i}o_i \cdot 1_{\{x\}}(\hat{p}_{i}(x))}{\sum_{i} 1_{\{x\}}(\hat{p}_{i}(x))}, x \in [0,1]$, that is the number of successes divided by the number of predictions for a probability value $x$. For a perfect predictor, $f(x)=x$.

What I am doing right now is trying to estimate $f$ by calculating $\hat{f}(x)=\frac{\sum_{i} K(\frac{x-x_i}{h}) \cdot o_i}{\sum_{i} K(\frac{x-x_i}{h})}$, where for $K$ I currently use the [Epanechnikov Kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epanechnikov_kernel). The remaining question is: how do I properly set the bandwidth parameter $h$? I am aware that there are methods to select an optimal bandwidth for Kernel Density Estimation, but since this is not KDE, I am not sure on how to proceed here.

Comment: You have to select the criterion you want to minimise/maximise and the find the optimal bandwidth. An alternative is using automatic nonparametric estimation, such as the one proposed [here](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~rjs57/CSSRevLV.pdf). The R packages [LogConcDEAD](http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/lib.stat.cmu.edu/R/CRAN/doc/packages/LogConcDEAD.pdf) and [logcondens](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/logcondens/logcondens.pdf) might be of interest if you find this approach appealing.