# Evaluating Classification Models with Class Probabilities

Tags: model-evaluation

I'm curious to see if there are any useful metrics to evaluate classification models using numeric probabilities.

Traditionally, I would train a classification model, generate factor predictions on the test set, and use a confusion matrix or ROC curve to decide on the best models. However, in this instance, I'm interested in doing model evaluation from looking at the numeric probablities.

**Update**

An example of what I'm talking about is this: I fit a multiple models and have it predict classes on the test set. Usually I can create a confusion matrix

**Model 1**

```
     Yes  No

 Yes  10   5
 No    2  13
```

**Model 2**

```
     Yes  No

 Yes   3  11
 No    8   8
```

From the confusion matrix, I can clearly tell that model 1 is more accurate than model 2.

How would I evaluate two models if I have them give me numeric probablities instead, for instance:

```
Model-1 Preds    Model-2 Preds     Test Set 
    .59               .25             No
    .14               .08             No
      .                 .              .
      .                 .              .
      .                 .              .
    .33               .29            Yes
```

I have thoughts of discretizing them or converting the yes and no's into 1 and 0's and calculating the residuals. Just wanted to know if there are more formal best practices to use in this case.

Comment: Can you give an example / some context to make this more concrete? Are you asking if it's possible to evaluate a model based on the predicted probability of success for cases without comparing those probabilities to a threshold and classifying them as successes & failures?

Comment: @gung, I have added an example, hopes this helps! :)

Comment: See e.g [Determine accuracy of model which estimates probability of event](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/20534/17230) & Gneiting & Raftery (2007), "Strictly proper scoring rules, prediction, & estimation", *JASA* **102**, 477.

Comment: Thank you for adding that. The answer is going to be to use something like the Brier score (there are also other options). It is discussed in the linked thread.